# Passing query but still getting None while printing kwargs.get(query_field)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**URL:** http://localhost:8000/policy-portal2020/super-mentor/dashboard/team?id=12

---

#### view

```py
@csrf_exempt
def team(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    if kwargs.get('id'):
        return JsonResponse({"name": "params"})
    elif request.user.is_super_mentor:
        return JsonResponse({"name": "not-param"})

    return JsonResponse({"msg": "error"})
```

---

#### output screenshoot

[image]

#### console output

- I am getting an empty dictionary {}

---

#### Why is it giving an empty dictionary though i have passed parameter to the url ?

Answer (score 1):

You obtain the parameters in the queryset through [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET), not the `**kwargs`. The `**kwargs` are parameters from the *path*. `request.GET` is a `QueryDict`, a dictionary-like object that represents the *querysetring* of the URL. So you should use:

```
@csrf_exempt
def team(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.GET.get('id'):
        return JsonResponse({"name": "params"})
    elif request.user.is_super_mentor:
        return JsonResponse({"name": "not-param"})
    return JsonResponse({"msg": "error"})
```